# Unable to change site multisite EE3

Tags: multi-site-manager, ee3, cookies

I have a multisite in my project but when I go to the cp and try to switch sites, the page simply refreshes and stays on the default site. When I open incognito in Chrome, login and try this again is **does** work, but when I then switch back to the default site and try to switch to the sub site again it simply refreshes again and stays on the default site.

It seems like some kind of cookie problem. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your backend, under **Settings > Security & Privacy** choose `CP session type` to **Session ID Only**